# Disable icon bounce in Plank

Tags: plank, themes

I am trying to figure out how to disable the launcher icon bounce in Plank. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure this is Freya-specific. Someone more knowledgeable should edit the question to remove that if it indeed is not the case.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a custom theme that disables the bounce animation by following these steps:

1. You will first need to create a new directory for the custom theme. It is important that you give it a unique name that does not conflict with any existing theme names.

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/plank/themes/no-bounce
   ```
2. Assuming that you are using the default theme (elementary), make a copy of the theme to your user directory. Other default themes are located in `/usr/share/plank/themes`.

   ```
   cp /usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme ~/.local/share/plank/themes/no-bounce/
   ```
3. Edit the theme file.

   ```
   scratch-text-editor ~/.local/share/plank/themes/no-bounce/dock.theme
   ```
4. Look for the line that starts with `LaunchBounceTime`. Modify it to `LaunchBounceTime=0`. Save the file and exit the editor.
5. Open your dock settings to change it to the custom theme.

   ```
   scratch-text-editor ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings
   ```
6. Look for the line that starts with `Theme`. Modify it to `Theme=no-bounce`. Save the file and exit the editor.

Your dock icons should no longer bounce when you launch them.

Comment: Nice job! Excellent answer!

Comment: Excellent Thank You. I got impatient and installed Dockbarx which I wanted to see work with elementary or not. After the next install I do I will follow these directions and work with Plank. Thanks again.